# ion-select ngModel not being update with ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

My app is deployed with Ionic 3 and now i’m into the process of migrating to Ionic 4.

One problem im having with Ionic 4 is with the ion-select using ngModel and ngModelChange,
it seems when i select one option the ngModel isn't updated so the ngModelChange isn't dispatched.

My code:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>{{ 'Model' | translate }}</ion-label>
    <ion-select name="model" [(ngModel)]="device.model" (ngModelChange)="updateFirmwareList()" [disabled]="!isNew"
              required #model="ngModel" [cancelText]="ionSelecNameCancel" [okText]="ionSelecNameOk" ngDefaultControl>
              <ion-select-option *ngFor="let model of modelList" [value]="model">{{ model }}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

- I have already loaded the module FormsModule.
- No errors are being displayed.
- Im calling the component from a ModalController.

Answer (score 2):

If you checked in both ionic 3 and 4 `ngModelChange` event get called after you click **Ok** button of modal.

I have created a sample demo with your code on **StackBlitz** with your below code. I am getting an event when I click on Ok button.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>{{ 'Model' }}</ion-label>
    <ion-select name="model" [(ngModel)]="device.model" (ngModelChange)="updateFirmwareList()" [disabled]="!isNew" required #model="ngModel"
     [cancelText]="ionSelecNameCancel" [okText]="ionSelecNameOk" ngDefaultControl>
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let model of modelList" [value]="model">{{ model }}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

TS

```
 updateFirmwareList() {
    console.log('Event Called');
  }
```

**[Ionic 3 Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-select-sample-srwcd8?file=pages/home/home.html)**

**[Ionic 4 Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-iynabb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: One point that may be causing this problem is that i'm opening this window inside a ModalController.

const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({ component: FormDevice, componentProps: {}, cssClass: 'full-size' });
await modal.present();

Comment: It didn't solve my problem because i need it working from a ModalController the way it was with Ionic 3.